# Chaos monkey testing for Microsoft Orleans cluster

Tags: orleans, chaos

I’m looking for some guidance that will help to design a “chaos monkey” testing approach for Orleans cluster.

I’m new on that, so what I can think is a script that can randomly restart silo’s, stop/move grains, and do other destructive actions. Something similar to [Induce Controlled Chaos in Service Fabric Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-controlled-chaos).

I’ll highly appreciate a help to get me on speed by sharing

- Good articles, whitepapers, blog post on Orleans cluster chaos testing
- Examples of using build in facilities like TestingSiloHost to conduct chaos tests
- Related Orleans Contrib projects
- Higher level tools/APIs that can help when hosting in VMs, AWS, Azure, Google Cloud

Thanks,

Comment: I don't believe there are any white papers on this (yet). Much of the stuff in the document you cite would be applicable though. I'm doing a deep dive through the dox right now, I'll come back here if I find anything.

Comment: perhaps you could use the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-controlled-chaos while running orleans in ServiceFabric

Comment: Might want to add onto your question and identify if you are planning to host on-premise or in a cloud provider to help folks provide some detailed answers.